# history.push is not working after login function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-functional-component

I am trying to use `history.push()` after setting the token. Somehow the page doesn't redirect to a new path. I have used `useHistory` feature for accessing history. Once I reload the page it is redirecting to home. I tried other sort of hacks but unable to find solution. Please help.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(cookie.get('authorization')){
      setAuthenticated(true);
    }
    else{
      setAuthenticated(false);
    }
  },[])
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          {isAuthenticated?<Redirect to="/home"/>:<Login />}
        </Route>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/user/:id" component={UserDetail} auth={isAuthenticated} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/createuser" component={CreateUser} auth={isAuthenticated} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={ListUser} auth={isAuthenticated} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**login.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

function Login() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const loginUser = (body) => {
        SetLoader(true);
        fetch('/api/v2/users/tokens', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                SetLoader(false);
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    SetError(false);   
                    cookie.set('authorization',response.headers.map.authorization,{path:'/'});
                    history.push('/');
                }
                else {
                    SetError(true);
                    StoreResponse(JSON.parse(response._bodyInit).message);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: I can't see the `const history = useHistory()` part. maybe adding that should work.

Comment: I have added @Chanandrei. It is not shown there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where `history` is defined in `Login` component. Also, you set the cookie, but `isAuthenticated` is only ever set when `App` component mounts, it is never updated later.

You could pass a callback to `Login` to update the state in `App` and let the redirect happen naturally when `App` rerenders and rerenders the routes with the re-enclosed `isAuthenticated` state. The `Switch` also already attempts to match and render routes exclusively, so order your paths most specific to least specific and you won't need to add the `exact` prop to every route.

App

```
function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cookie.get("authorization")) {
      setAuthenticated(true);
    } else {
      setAuthenticated(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute
          path="/user/:id"
          component={UserDetail}
          auth={isAuthenticated}
        />
        <PrivateRoute
          path="/createuser"
          component={CreateUser}
          auth={isAuthenticated}
        />
        <PrivateRoute
          path="/home"
          component={ListUser}
          auth={isAuthenticated}
        />
        <Route path="/">
          {isAuthenticated ? (
            <Redirect to="/home" />
          ) : (
            <Login setAuthenticated={setAuthenticated} /> // <-- pass callback
          )}
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Login

```
function Login({ setAuthenticated }) { // <-- destructure prop
  const loginUser = (body) => {
    SetLoader(true);
    fetch("/api/v2/users/tokens", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          SetError(false);
          cookie.set("authorization", response.headers.map.authorization, {
            path: "/"
          });
          setAuthenticated(true); // <-- set authenticated
        } else {
          SetError(true);
          StoreResponse(JSON.parse(response._bodyInit).message);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        SetLoader(false); // <-- set loading false in finally block
      });
  };

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The callback method works. I imported useHistory from react-router-dom. I haven't mentioned it in the code here. Now I have updated in the code. Still history.push doesn't work.

Comment: @SriharshaK `Login` is a functional component ***and*** it is rendered within a `Router`, so I see no reason why a `history.push` *wouldn't* work. Could you provide a bit more detail about what isn't working? Is there an error? Does it navigate at all?

Comment: @DrewReese I had the same problem and while this did initiate the redirect, I'm getting this error: `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.` I'm not using `componentDidUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`, just `useEffect` and basicly the same configuration you gave above.

Comment: @idanicoleherbert `useEffect` with a dependency is equivalent to a class-based component's `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. You are likely unconditionally updating some state that is a dependency for the effect. Is this a new question? Feel free to ask a new SO question and (at) me here and I can take a look.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for the quick response, I managed to fix it by cutting out the `useEffect` in App,keeping the ternary router and adding a  `window.location.reload()` in the login post request instead of the setter ^~^